# What are the best computer generators for historical timelines?

Tags: campaign-development, tool-recommendation, generator

Every world or campaign setting has a timeline of historical events. Normally this has the format of a year number followed by a short description. For example:

**−9800 DR**: The Yuirwood was settled by green elves in the aftermath of the Crown Wars.

**−6950 DR**: The star elves began leaving other elven nations and gathering in the Yuirwood.

**−6600 DR**: The star and green elves founded the realm of Yuireshanyaar in the Yuirwood.

(Example from [Forgotten Realms Wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/History_of_the_Yuirwood_%28timeline%29))

I wonder if there are generators that can create a random timeline to use it in my own campaing. I tried this generator: http://orfinlir.de/3rdE/historyX.php, but perhaps there are better options.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Unfortunately in its current format this question is not a good fit for this site as it is too broad. In order for it to be improved you will need to provide a definition of what a 'good generator' is from your point of view.

Comment: Yes, you have to be a little bit more specific in what information the generator will create, and perhaps even in how it conveys this information. What sort of events are you looking for? Wars between nations? Demonic invasions? Meteorfalls? Natural disasters? As of now this is simply a "list" question of generators, and therefore a little off-topic.

Comment: Also: is this for solo creation, or is it acceptable to involve/require other people?

Comment: Also, is this something you want your group to collaborate in? or are you looking to do a DM of the Rings infographic dump?

Comment: I edited the question to fit the requirements of the moderators. I tried to make the question more specific, related to computer generators and timelines instead of generators and history in general.

Comment: If I were you, I'd unaccept that answer, and wait for them to come in.  I think this is a very good question, and should get some interesting answers.  But I've noticed from experience that once an answer is accepted, the other answers tend to stop rolling in.

Comment: Yeah, definitely take your time accepting an answer for this one. There isn't any pressure to accept an answer (especially not right away), and if you do it's not going to do you any good, just discourage new answers.

Answer (score 10):

The simulationist computer game Dwarf Fortress (http://www.bay12games.com/dwarves/) has a 'legends' mode that is, in essence, a world history generator and will also provide an (evolving) map.

It is noted for its depth in culture/world details, so it might be a good fit; and our gaming group has used it for world map/location/NPC generation.

Answer (score 8):

**[Microscope](http://www.lamemage.com/microscope/)** is an rpg that, over the course of play, generates a history. You can use it to create a shared world as a group, and then bootstrap into using it as a setting for a different rpg.

Answer (score 6):

[**Dawn of Worlds**](http://clanwebsite.org/games/rpg/Dawn_of_Worlds_game_1_0Final.pdf) is a collaborative narrative game in which two or more people portray the "gods" of a fantasy world and create the world's history in three "ages".  It's free and fun.  In your case, I would simply start in the Third Age.

It's possible to play it solo, although it's more fun if you get someone else involved.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Rosenfelder's *Planet Construction Kit* book doesn't act as a generator by itself, but it gives you step-by-step instructions for figuring out the history of your society.

Answer (score -1):

The 2nd Edition AD&D book "World Builders Guidebook" has a chapter on history.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE Infyra.  The question is asking for a computer generated timeline.  Can you explain how the 2d edition AD&D book will provide that?  While you are at it, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how a Q&A site in the SE format is different from a discussion forum.  In particular, have a look at [how to write a good answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).